# Why was the ack number decreased to 1?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I am trying to get TCP. From **TCP RFC 793** server and client select a random sequence numbers and after they increase it each time when it receives a new byte (it is wrong but just for example). To dump TCP packages I used `tcpdump -n -i eth0 tcp`:

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
04:32:20.732914 IP 10.10.0.2.43168 > 10.50.0.2.9: S 372254521:372254521(0) 
    win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 3644068 0,nop,wscale 1>
04:32:20.766194 IP 10.50.0.2.9 > 10.10.0.2.43168: S 363863555:363863555(0) 
    ack 372254522 win 5792 <mss 536,sackOK,timestamp 3644074 3644068,nop,wscale 1>
04:32:20.766416 IP 10.10.0.2.43168 > 10.50.0.2.9: . 
    ack 1 win 2920 <nop,nop,timestamp 3644073 3644074>
04:32:25.502532 IP 10.10.0.2.43168 > 10.50.0.2.9: P 1:7(6) 
    ack 1 win 2920 <nop,nop,timestamp 3644548 3644074>
04:32:25.503272 IP 10.50.0.2.9 > 10.10.0.2.43168: . 
    ack 7 win 2896 <nop,nop,timestamp 3644548 3644548>
04:32:29.510131 IP 10.10.0.2.43168 > 10.50.0.2.9: F 7:7(0) 
    ack 1 win 2920 <nop,nop,timestamp 3644949 3644548>
04:32:29.513123 IP 10.50.0.2.9 > 10.10.0.2.43168: F 1:1(0) 
    ack 8 win 2896 <nop,nop,timestamp 3644949 3644949>
04:32:29.513356 IP 10.10.0.2.43168 > 10.50.0.2.9: . 
    ack 2 win 2920 <nop,nop,timestamp 3644949 3644949>
```

The first two packages look normally but from the third and so on it uses `ack 1` instead of `363863556` and I can't get **why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It hasn't.  You are running `tcpdump` without telling it that you want to see *absolute sequence numbers* (`-S`).

The default behavior for `tcpdump` is to translate sequence numbers to *relative* sequence numbers, which allow you to see how many bytes of data have transferred in either direction.  In this specific case, you are seeing it go to 1 because, according to RFC-793, the SYN consumes one byte in the stream, so the proper response is SEQ+1.  You will see the same thing happen going the other direction.  (You will also find that the FIN consumes one byte).  Following this, the ACK will increase by the number of bytes sent.

If you want to see the absolute sequence numbers, try again running `tcpdump -n -i eth0 -S tcp`